# How to build llvm example's ModuleMaker by using clang++

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm trying to build ModuleMaker from the LLVM example.

When I invoke:

```
clang++ -g ModuleMaker.cpp `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core jit native` -o ModuleMaker
```

I received the error message:

```
/home/huangered/Desktop/ModuleMaker/main.cpp:59: undefined reference to `llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile(llvm::Module const*, llvm::raw_ostream&)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clang++ main.cpp `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core jit native bitwriter` -o main
```

o.i get it. i should add a bitwriter component into the llvm-config.